# Request Entity Too Large Liferay Tomcat

Tags: liferay, portlet

I am getting the following error in Liferay(tomcat server) while uploading documents.

**Request Entity Too Large**

The requested resource
/MyPortal/group/control_panel/manage
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

My code is as follows.

```
FileEntry Dlfile = DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry(
                themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), folderId,
                FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getFileName()), uploadedFile.getContentType(),
                uploadedFile.getFileName(), "", "", uploadedFile.getInputstream(),
                uploadedFile.getSize(), serviceContextFile);
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

please check the size of the document you are uploading
Your can use these two properties to raise the max size

```
com.liferay.portal.upload.UploadServletRequestImpl.max.size
dl.file.max.size
```

Comment: i set it as #dl.file.max.size=307200 in the portal-ext.properties

Comment: if this is literally what you have in portal-ext.properties, you have nothing: # is the comment character, the line needs to start with *dl.*, not with *#*

Comment: sorry, i have 
dl.file.max.size=307200000

Comment: please post your stacktrace